# http adapter for https protocol

Tags: https, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I want to read an xml file with http adapter,but the protocol is https. I think the solution will consist to transform   like this :

```
 <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>https</protocol>
            <domain>greenhouse.lotus.com</domain>
            <port>443</port>
            <authentication>
                <basic/>
                <serverIdentity>
                    <username> ${user} </username>
                    <password> ${password} </password>
                </serverIdentity>
            </authentication>  
        </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
    </connectivity>
```

If it this the solution, please can you tell me how to create ${user} and ${password}. Else show me other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear...
It is also not clear what is your IBM MobileFirst version. I will assume it is 7.1...

Do you want $user and $password to be taken from this XML file, or do you want to try and access an XML file using the adapter?

You cannot simply read values from an XML file and place them in elements in the adapter configuration file (seen above). Also note that you **cannot change this file during runtime**. The way to do it is either via JNDI properties or via custom properties in the worklight.properties file.

- Find the worklight.properties file in the you-project/server/ folder.
- Add a new line, for example: `myPassword=test`.
- Then, in the XML, use: `<password>${myPassword}</password>`